# How to get text produced by pdf.js in page view source ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-canvas, pdf.js

I am working on an application in which a pdf is converted to html5 by "pdf.js".Project requirements are that the html rendered by pdf.js should contains text of the pdf in page view source so that we can perform our further processing on it.

I have read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/466362/Blend-PDF-with-HTML but it has no option for text rendering.
Also this http://git.macropus.org/2011/11/pdftotext/example/

How to get text in a pdf in the form of divs in page view source when converted to html5 by pdf.js?

Comment: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/text-only

Comment: there is also svg backend for pdf.js, you may need to use that instead of canvas

Comment: being as the text is generated via Javascript, it will never show up in page view source. Viewing page source shows the raw HTML prior to executing any javascript.

Answer (score 0):

PDF.JS only supplies a textlayer which is added on top of the viewer to enable text to be selectable, it doesn't create divs for images and graphics - these artefacts are rendered to a html5 canvas.